# A domain-covariant notation for functions?

Tags: functions, transformation, change-of-basis

**Note:** I'm using the terms "covariant" and "contravariant" a bit loosely in this question.

The standard function notation seems to be naturally codomain-covariant and domain-contravariant. And we have seen examples of this since the very first algebra class. In order to translate a function upwards, we add to the result; in order to translate a function to the right, we subtract from the argument.

This generalizes to general compositions of functions. In order to transform the $y$ axis of the graph of some function $y=f(x)$ by some function $g(\cdot)$, we can just compose it as such: $y_{[y]}=g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x)$. However, if we want to transform the $x$ axis of the graph of the function $y=f(x)$ by some function $h(\cdot)$, we need to compose the argument with the inverse of that function: $y_{[x]}=f(h^{-1}(x))=f\big((I\circ h^{-1})(x)\big)$. Note that, strictly speaking, the transformation is first and foremost done *on the graph* rather than the functions, and only then it translates into functional identities through domain contravariance and codomain covariance. This resembles basis transformation and just screams "Jacobian" to me, although I don't know where exactly it's hiding and how the covariance/contravariance factors in.

The question is, what exactly is it about functional notation in its essence, as a representation of an abstract mathematical object, that makes it naturally act this way? And is it possible to construct a function notation that is covariant with respect to both the domain and the codomain?